# Unable to delete lucene file in %temp% folder windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, temporary-files

I have a computer running Window 7 Ultimate. When I try to delete all the files in the %temp% folder a file named **lucene-b0c1305e43fd8579e46466c31b4fedb9-commit.lock** keeps on generating again and again, and I am not able to delete it.

How can I delete it and prevent it from reappearing?

Comment: Does it come back even after rebooting? Try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to see what process has it locked, and/or [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what process recreates it.

Comment: http://blog.tfd.co.uk/2007/09/05/lucen-lock-files-that-wont-go-away/

Comment: http://java.sys-con.com/node/37296

Answer (score 2):

A process called NMIndexStoreSvr.exe was creating the **lucene-9280b370d1038bf9b464c630bb1fed8c-commit.LOCK** file in my Temp folder.

NMIndexStoreSvr.exe is a Nero Home process and seems to be unnecessary for any functionality. Because of quick flashing of this file, I couldn't use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> command to select all the files and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

So I started the Windows Task Manager, went to the Processes tab and found out that the NMIndexStoreSvr.exe process was using about 25% of my CPU resource and was creating the **lucene** temporary file.

When I killed the NMIndexStoreSvr.exe process the **lucene** file stopped appearing in my Temp folder.

The NMIndexStoreSvr.exe file was located (at least for me) in the following folder:
C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Ahead\Lib\NMIndexStoreSvr.exe

To find the file, open Task Manager, click on the Processes tab, right-click on the NMIndexStoreSvr.exe process and select the "Open File Location" option which will take you directly to where the .exe file is located.

I renamed this file to something else and the **lucene** file stopped appearing in my Temp folder.